# How do I pass a target parameter to a CakePHP redirect?

Tags: cakephp, iframe, redirect

I have a module built in CakePHP that is hosted within an iFrame.  I need to have a redirect target the parent page.  Using normal HTML I do:

```
<a href="#" target="_parent">
```

But how do I do that for CakePHP redirect?

```
$this->redirect('http://www.url.com');
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a link with a `target` attribute, or are you trying to `redirect` from the Controller. That's two different things.

Answer (score 3):

A "redirect" is actually done using the HTTP protocol, meaning it's totally transparent to the user and no HTML is loaded.

What you are trying to do is create a link in an HTML page. So, you can't use redirect() to do this, because redirect() uses a lower layer than HTML.

You'll have to create a page with an HTML redirect (there are several ways to do this, google will help you).

Answer (score 0):

Taking a stab at an answer:

`$this->redirect()` redirects by issuing an HTTP response code, i.e. the HTTP header will make the browser redirect. There's no concept of a "target" in HTTP response codes, so you can't redirect a parent frame using this technique.

Your user will have to click on a `target="_parent"` link himself, or you have to use other techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', $id));` where `$id` is the id of the post you want to redirect to.